# VS Code suggestions do not display documentation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, documentation

My VS code suggestions will not display any documentation next to the suggestions. What settings do I need to change? I have editor>suggest>show inline details active but it is doing it.

Here is mine:
[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I am using python.

I tried searching through the settings. I tried looking it up on the internet. I tried looking at these GitHub issues:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18582

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/25812

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the space is too small. This setting has been deprecated. You can use the following alternatives:

Use command **"ctrl + space"** when you get intellisense:

[image]

And this is a switch. You only need to use this command once, and you can get the prompt of this window in the future.

Comment: do you know whats the setting for it? clicking didn't pop the details for me

Comment: found it thats the `toggleSuggestionDetails` setting, which can also be `cmd+i`